# Editing a closed question: where are the edits?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions, revisions-list

*[How do I generate a random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964604/)* was closed. From the comments, it's clear that the asker completely changed his question.

I wanted to see the original question—the original edit/version—so I hit the "edit" button. I don't see any previous revisions though.

I don't want to edit the question, but I do want to see the history of edits.

Comment: It's been merged, so that link no longer works. But what likely happened was that the edits were within the five-minute window. (Try editing your question right now and notice that there is no revision history generated.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2964604/revisions tells me that there is only one revision. And the first comment indicates that the poster did a blinding fast edit, so it was probably within the first 5 minutes. There is no way to retrieve the previous revisions of a single 5 minute block.

Comment: @mmyers It doesn't look merged, the error screen is because the URL says "posts" instead of "questions". You'd get identical results looking at this question as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/52359/

Comment: @ccomet: Huh, I thought "posts" was equivalent to "questions" for the most part. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edits probably occurred during the 5-minute window that serves as a grace period for edits in progress.  Any edits that take place during that 5 minute window are not logged in the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

[**http://example.com/posts/{ID}/revisions**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2964604/revisions)

Comment: +1 for telling me about that /revisions bit - I've wanted exactly that sort've thing before, and now I know how to get it!

Comment: @Frank: Just a note, this URL works for both questions *and* answers.